# Microsoft Office preview shows a different document in alfresco share

Tags: ms-office, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am sure, a question regarding Microsoft Office preview in share has been asked previously, but I am facing a strange issue. The preview for document A shows up Document B in Alfresco share. Earlier it was showing a previous version, but now it shows a totally different document. When the user downloads it, its the right document. And this happens only with some files, especially files with .xks, .xlsx extension.
What could be causing this ? 
Its confusing the users and would really appreciate if someone could give pointer on how the issue can be fixed.

Thanks.

Comment: Any errors in the logs? What version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: Hi @Mardoz, no errors and I am using Alfresco community 4.2.f. As I read online, the preview is swf content transformed from xls to pdf to swf. It looks like a caching issue. Some old document thumbnail is getting fetched related to the new document. Is there a way to not use the cached results. One way I figured out was to comment out the loop which looks for cached content in the javascript file web-preview.js. But is that the right thing to do?

Comment: After searching a lot, ultimately it was just a problem of corrupt document.